# How to read bytes from a json in python?

Tags: python, json, byte

I got a json file that has utf-8 escape characters (because it has Cyrillic data). It was a response that I got from an API request.

The file looks similar to this (I only show the structure because it's really long):

```
b'{"objectId":"39:0:0:343",""objectData":{"objectName":"\xd0\xa3\xd0\xba\xd1\x80\xd1\x8b\xd1\x82\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb5 \xe2\x84\x96198","removed":0,"objectAddress":{"district":null,"districtType":"\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80",}},"oldNumbers":[{"tempId":0}, {"regionKey":139}]}'
```

So as I understand, I need to decode this byte to a string with normal Cyrillic UTF-8 characters, because I need to make a pandas Dataframe. I have tried pd.read_json, json.load(), json.loads(), but every time I get different errors because Python opens the json as a string, not a byte. I can't do the `bytes.decode('utf-8)` since I don't know how to read the .json as a byte.

When I try `open(filename, 'rb')`, it returns a BufferedReader object, not a bytes object!

I've been working with json only for two days, so I'm sorry if my question sounds dumb.
——————————————————————

To be clear, I'll give my exact code:

```
with open(os.getcwd() + "/39_00_000000_343.json", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json_data = json.loads(f.read())
```

It raises `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`
As I understand, it's because the byte was not converted to Unicode text and the file starts with a 'b'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `open(filename, encoding="utf-8")`.

This will give you Unicode strings that are already decoded.

Re: the code to use to generate the contents of the file:

```
r2 = requests.get(url)
with open('saint-p/passports/' + cad + '.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as output_file:
    output_file.write(r2.text)
```

The trick with all of this encoding complexity is to realize that bytes are the raw encoded form of Unicode strings. In Python a unicode string character "looks" like a single unit, but can be "encoded" into two or more bytes depending on what encoding you are using.

So in this case, the JSON is coming at you from the server as encoded bytes in the HTTP response. Then the requests library is decoding that for you into the `.text` Unicode string attribute. Then you are opening a file that accepts Unicode strings for writing and writes the encoded "utf-8" bytes out to the file for you automatically. Then you are doing the opposite and having python open a "utf-8" bytes encoded file and decode it automatically to Unicode strings on read().

Finally, you then take that Unicode string and feed it into the JSON decoder.

So, if you were to skip the intermediate file, it would look like:

```
r2 = requests.get(url)
json_data = json.loads(r2.text)
```

Comment: I tried the .read() method to look into the variable and I found out that the byte was not converted: it looks like b'....' but nothing is decoded. Now it's just a string that got b'' inside what ruins the parsing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like what's been written to the file is a Python representation of a JSON compatible data structure - not actually JSON. What's the code that generated it look like?

Comment: Here it is:  
`r2 = requests.get(url)
 with open('saint-p/passports/' + cad + '.json', 'w') as output_file:
     output_file.write(str(r2.text.encode("utf-8")))`

Comment: Try this: `r2 = requests.get(url)  with open('saint-p/passports/' + cad + '.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as output_file:      output_file.write(r2.text)`